# Como inverter data de um grid

Tags: c#

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tenho um banco de dados com algumas tabelas para controle de vendas de softwares, e dentre estas tabelas, tenho a de softwares que contem os campos, inicio do contrato e fim do contrato.
Só que quando dou o select ao inves de aparecerem assim ''21/12/2016'' elas aparecem assim no grid ''12/21/2016''       Alguma solução ?

```
private void MontarLista()
    {

        conexao.ConnectionString = strconexao;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SOFTWARES";
        cmd.Connection = conexao;

        conexao.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DtSoftwares.Clear();
        DtSoftwares.Load(Dr);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSoftwares;
        conexao.Close();
        decimal soma = 0;


        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
```

Comment: magnetun.mdf        tabela softwares   colunas que preciso   inicio   e termino

Comment: trabalho com banco de dados sql server, mas estou usando local .mdf

Comment: Web Forms ou Winds Forms?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer

```
string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.ParseExact("12/21/2016", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Você substitui o "21/12/2016" pela a sua string que esta a data, Ou se você já tiver o objeto DateTime, basta colocar ele ao invez do `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Answer (score 1):

Da forma atual, só vejo uma maneira simples de resolver. Formatar a data diretamente no select

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FORMAT(INICIO, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS INICIO, " + 
                        " OUTROS_CAMPOS FROM SOFTWARES";
```

Isso vai fazer com que a coluna `INICIO` seja formatada com o padrão brasileiro.

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FORMAT(CAMPO_DE_DATA, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS inicio, 
                         termino FROM SOFTWARES";

Comment: Ficara assim ! Mas o que eu coloco depois do format no lugar do campo_de_data?

Comment: O nome da coluna

Comment: de novo ? ja coloquei no final inicio e termino , que sao as duas colunas

Comment: De novo o que? Não tô entendendo qual é o problema...

Comment: Pode deixar, eu é que nao estou sabendo implementar, muitooo obrigado , vou ver se coloco um datepicker

Comment: @RennanHanna no `CAMPO_DE_DATA` você deve colocar no nome da coluna referente à data. Qual o nome do campo referente a data início? É início mesmo? Me refiro ao nome que está na sua classe Softwares.

Comment: tenho dois campos com data , inicio e termino .

Comment: deu problema na minha soma de colunas valor para exibir em um label. vou postar a foto.

Comment: mas eu só coloquei o campo inicio no lugar dos campos_data, preciso colocar termino , como eu faria ?